# Which site would NaCN attacks (SN2)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides, nucleophilic-substitution

**Question**

[image]

**Attempt**

I thought that the bromine atom farther from the ring would be substituted because of less hindrance, but the book says opposite, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reaction proceeds by SN2, which is highly accelerated at the benzylic position, due to stabilisation of the transition state by conjugation with the aromatic ring.

> [image]

So you'll have to replace the benzylic bromine.

**References:** [*Benzyl chloride: chemtube3d*](https://www.chemtube3d.com/sn2_benzylchloride_sh/)